# How to send extras from Service (start from alarm with Notification) to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

My `MainActivity` has `Alarm`. `Alarm` starts to repeat `Service` and send data to it from `intent.putExtra` from `pendingIntent`. When `Service` returns true, then it autocanсels itself (by new `pendingIntent` -> cancel) and sends data to `Notification` (if the user clicks on it, the app will start with new data from that `Notification` or the user only starts app -> it will load with new data). I need to send my `putExtras` from `Notification` to `MainActivity`, `getExtra` in `MainActivity`,  and (if that is possible) commit it automatically.

If I'm right, i must use `startActivityForResult` before calling `Service`, but how can I do this with `Alarm`?

P.S. already work all except for that step "`Notification.putExtras()` -> `MainActivity.getExtras()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for are [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

> A bound service is an implementation of the Service class that allows
>   other applications to bind to it and interact with it.

Take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#service_activitybinding) and let me know if it helped. 
Here they talk about the alternatives to communicate between service and activities:
[servicecommunication](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#servicecommunication) .

Comment: Thanks for help, but i don't understand.. it's new for me.. i must destroy my code? can u give me an example please? %)

Comment: Hi @user2583792. Did you see both links that i put in the answer? I think you should take time to reed this hole tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html